# Change the date format of react-calendar in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I used the react calendar for displaying the calendar. Currently when I try to access the date from its onChange method.

```
onChange = date => {
        console.log(date); //Sun Jul 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        this.setState({ date });
    }
```

I want to change this date format in something like this (07/18/2020).

I tried with the formatLongDate as per their documentation as I wasn't able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `toLocaleDateString` like the following:

```
onChange = date => {
    console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
    this.setState({ date: date.toLocaleDateString() });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```
onChange = date => {
        console.log(date); //Sun Jul 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        if (date instanceof Date) {
        this.setState({ date: date.toLocaleDateString()});
        }
}
```